javascript code processing in incorrect order
I am creating a chrome extension and for some reason the code is not being processed in the correct order.
let tenant;
const handleLogin = async () => {
  consoleLog('Logging in');
  IP = await getPublicIP();
  let uuid;

  chrome.storage.local.get(['uuid'], result => {
    uuid = result.uuid;
    consoleLog('uuid: ', uuid);
    consoleLog('tenant: ', tenant);
  });
  //check if user exists already


  //Check user profile
  if (!tenant) {
    consoleLog('Checking User Profile');
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo((userInfo) => {
      if (userInfo.email != "") {
        consoleLog('User is logged in browser', userInfo.email);
        if (!uuid) {
          uuid = userInfo.email;
        }

        chrome.storage.local.set({ browser_auth_verified: true });
        chrome.storage.local.set({ email: uuid });
        chrome.storage.local.set({ uuid });

        var emailDomain = getDomainWithoutTLD(userInfo.email);
        tenant = emailDomain;
        consoleLog('Domain is ', emailDomain);

        login(uuid, userInfo.email, userInfo.id);
      }
    });
  }

  consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant);
  consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant == null || tenant == undefined);
}

For some reason consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant); and consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant == null || tenant == undefined); are called before everything.

How specifically are you observing this behavior?  It seems much more likely that the code is being called in the correct order, but tenant simply has no value when you observe it because that value is being set asynchronously.

where is the async method in my code?

Right here: chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo((userInfo) => {  And here: chrome.storage.local.get(['uuid'], result => {  You're always encouraged to check the documentation as well.

getProfileUserInfo() and chrome.storage.local.get() are probably asynchronous since it accepts a callback (not everything that accepts a callback is async, for example Array.map() is not async). The best course of action is to convert them to Promises:
const getStorage = (arg) => {
  return new Promise((ok,fail) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(arg,ok);
  })
}

const getUserInfo = () => {
  return new Promise((ok,fail) => {
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(ok);
  })
}

Now you can just await it:
const handleLogin = async () => {
  consoleLog('Logging in');
  IP = await getPublicIP();
  let uuid;

  // HERE IS HOW YOU CALL getStorage:
  const result = await getStorage(['uuid']);

  uuid = result.uuid;
  consoleLog('uuid: ', uuid);
  consoleLog('tenant: ', tenant);

  //check if user exists already        
  //Check user profile
  if (!tenant) {
    consoleLog('Checking User Profile');

    // HERE IS HOW YOU CALL getUserInfo:
    const userInfo = await getUserInfo();

    if (userInfo.email != "") {
      consoleLog('User is logged in browser', userInfo.email);
      if (!uuid) {
        uuid = userInfo.email;
      }

      chrome.storage.local.set({ browser_auth_verified: true });
      chrome.storage.local.set({ email: uuid });
      chrome.storage.local.set({ uuid });

      var emailDomain = getDomainWithoutTLD(userInfo.email);
      tenant = emailDomain;
      consoleLog('Domain is ', emailDomain);

      login(uuid, userInfo.email, userInfo.id);
    }
  }

  consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant);
  consoleLog('Tenant ', tenant == null || tenant == undefined);
}

